# php - How to open a ssrs rdl file in php

Tags: php, windows, azure, reporting-services, windows-authentication

Hi friends I have a rdl file and they have given me the service url & username and password details.
In my php webpage i must place a run link for this rdl file.When the user clicks the rdl file the reports must be shown in my php webpage.

I have a googled and found this link http://ssrsphp.codeplex.com/ useful but could not able to figure out where to start.They have given a lot of procedures for this.I do notwant all those things.

I just want to run the rdl file and show its results
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. You can access Reporting services with the URL and have a web page or stream for some other file type returned to your php page, which you can send on to the user.

The .rdl file needs to be uploaded to the SSRS service one time, before you can request that it is rendered. Use the service url you were provided with, and make sure that you see the report there. Then test that you can run the report and see results. Now you can make calls to the service and get those results which can be used as needed.

(Note that the default url for SSRS management is usually similar to `https://servername/reports/` but the service is accessed at `https://servername/reportserver/`

Take a look at "URL Access" for a simple way of consuming SSRS:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153586.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Look into the URL Access for displaying SSRS Reports directly from the SSRS Server.

For example:

> http://serverName.local/ReportServer?/example/testReport&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=HTML4.0&rc:Toolbar=False

Will display your specified report in a browser. You can easily hook this into another website.